# Search for link in Mail and click on it without using the mouse

Tags: keyboard, mail.app, shortcut

Sometimes I receive an e-mail, which contains a link that I have to follow. I would like to be able to follow this link without having to reach for the mouse. I can locate the link with a search (cmd + F), but how do I follow it by pressing keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is possible without additional software, but it definitely works if you use the tool [Shortcat](https://shortcatapp.com/). With Shortcat, you can do a lot of things by keyboard that usually require a mouse.

I bought a license almost three years ago to support the project, but apparently you can still use it for free, because it has not officially left beta yet.